# Error : Detected background switch for MyApp(24) who has NO tunnels open - defocus NOT called

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-storm

when i run or debug my BB application  i got this `Detected background switch for MyApp(180) who has NO tunnels open - defocus NOT called` Error

i have no idea regarding this that how this error occur .
my application install in Simulator and device but no effect after click on application icon.

i have done clean all simulator and get suggetion from this url [link](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Detected-background-switch-for-MyApp-24-who-has-NO-tunnels-open/td-p/308545)

and change my rimpublic from eclipse >plugin > MDS > config folder

please let me some suggetion regarding same :(

Thanks in Advance !!!!

Answer (score 1):

Kindly clean the simulator.

work in blackberry perspective and you will see new buttons related to blackberry development!

Press the 'Clean Simulator' or Press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> and this will open box and asked choose the project.

Then select you project and try again to run your app!